# Need help to convert x86 ASM to x64

Tags: delphi, assembly, x86, x86-64, 32bit-64bit

I have a library that uses assembler code for some functions and I would like to compile it on x64, of course throwing erros. Could anyone be so kind as to correct it (and maybe even explain me WHY these functions are written in ASM)?

```
function Trunc(const x : Single) : Integer; register;
const cwChop : Word = $1F3F;
asm
      SUB     ESP,8
      FSTCW   [ESP]
      FLDCW   cwChop
      FLD     x
      FISTP   dword ptr [ESP+4]
      FLDCW   [ESP]
      POP     ECX
      POP     EAX
end;

function Frac(const x : Single) : Single; register;
begin
   Result := x - Trunc(x);
end;

function Round(const x : Single) : Integer; register;
asm
      SUB     ESP,4
      FLD     x
      FISTP   dword ptr [ESP]
      POP     EAX
end;
```

most humble thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a reason to implement these functions in assembler.  Modern Delphi compilers should be able to generate the same code just fine.  However, I'm not too familiar with Pascal or Delphi, so I don't feel comfortable writing an answer.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you'd write the first one by hand in asm.  That's horrible, like the kind of thing you'd try to *avoid* by hand-writing asm to use SSE3 FISTTP or SSE2 `CVTTSS2SI eax, xmm0`.  Given that SSE math (the default for x86-64) has conversion with truncation directly supported, I'd hope than any compiler knows how to use it, but check the asm.  (And non-truncating conversion with `cvtss2si`, which you can't as easily access in C; you have to hand-hold your compiler into inlining lrint(x) or `(int)rint(x)` and optimizing away overhead;  IDK about Delphi)

Comment: Bizarre question. Use the RTL functions with the same names.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I was wondering the same, but thought of some optimzation reasons. I will gladly remove them :-)